# Changing a field to required in serializer based on values given in request

Tags: validation, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an API endpoint that (in this simplified example) creates a "Stuff" Object, it has fields that are only required based on the value of one of the other fields.

As a rough example, the following requests are valid:

```
{
"type": "A"
"name": "Steve"
"Afield1": "hello"
"Afield2": "goodbye"
}
```

and

```
{
"type": "B"
"name": "Paul"
}
```

The following is not, because `Afield1` and `Afield2` should be required fields when `type` = A

```
{
"type": "A"
"name": "Steve"
}
```

It should return this error:

```
{
    "Afield1": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
    "Afield2": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Which is the standard error from a missing field in Django Rest Framework. Specifically, the error dictionary is constructed in `to_internal_values()` in the `serializer.py` file.

The serializer however must define these fields as `required=False` because In order for a type "B" request to be valid, the fields for type "A" must be optional.

As such, the serializer looks like this:

```
class StuffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Afield1 = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    Afield2 = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

I am looking for a way to change required to True conditionally after the request has been made. I tried accessing the `required` attribute on the Field from the serializer, but it does not seem to take effect on the actual Field Object.

```
class StuffSerializer():

    def create(self, validated_stuff_data) -> Stuff:
            for field in ["Afield1","Afield2"]:
                if field not in validated_stuff_data:
                    # This gets the Field object for the missing field,
                    # and sets it to be required. This does NOT work
                    # because the change is not reflected on the field
                    # that gets validated after this loop
                    missing_field = self.get_fields()[field]
                    missing_field.required = True
            # This calls validation for serializer
            self.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Again, rather than raise my own custom validation error, I would like to utilize the existing validation logic in DRF.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the [validate](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) method in the serializer.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class StuffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Afield1 = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    Afield2 = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    def validate(self, attrs: dict) -> dict:
        type = attrs.get("type", None)
        field_1 = attrs.get("field_1", None)
        field_2 = attrs.get("field_2", None)

        # your condition
        if type == "A":
            if field_1 is None and field_2 is None:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Both `field_1` and `field_2` are required")
        
        return attrs
```

If the `validate` method raises an error, the error will be in this format

```json
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Both `field_1` and `field_2` are required"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Again, I need to use the existing validation logic of DRF, not raise a custom ValidationError as you have done here.